# npx react-native init fails on Installing Bundler

Tags: node.js, ruby, react-native, npx

I have been trying to create a new react-native app with the command `npx react-native init SamepleApp` but it fails on Installing Bundler with the following issue

Attached Image showing error

[image: 1]

I tried updating my ruby version to the latest version but it also did not help. I have been using MacBook Pro 2017 with Intel Chip and my ruby version is 2.6.10p210, Node version is v16.17.1 and no react-native-CLI is globally installed

I am trying to figure out a solution to a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not a Mac user, but you may be able to make use of `asdf-vm`.

1. Follow the step over [here](https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html) to install `asdf`. Make sure to add them to the config file (in your case, `.zshrc`).
2. Head over to [`asdf-ruby`](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-ruby) and install the Ruby plugin. Before that, make sure that you have the required dependencies ([check here](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/wiki#suggested-build-environment)).
3. Optionally, you may also choose to install [`asdf-nodejs`](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-nodejs) and follow the steps below for the same. Again, make sure to install the required dependencies ([check here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/BUILDING.md)).
4. Install the required version using `asdf install <plugin> <version>`, eg:

   ```bash
   $ asdf install ruby 3.1.1
   ```
5. After installing, you may want to run `asdf reshim`.
6. To set the plugin version globally, run `asdf global <plugin> <version>`, eg:

   ```bash
   $ asdf global ruby 3.1.1
   ```

   OR

   To set the version locally (that is, for a particular directory), run `asdf local <plugin> <version>`, eg:

   ```bash
   $ asdf local ruby 3.1.1
   ```
7. Check all the version installed using `asdf list`. Check your active versions using `asdf current`.

Comment: It still did not work.

Comment: @AbdulAhad that is a vague comment. Without sharing logs, I am afraid I cannot help you out. What does `ruby -v` say? Does it show the newer version you wanted to install?