# Changing gem env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, react-native, terminal, rubygems

I am new to Using changing ruby and have been having a lot of trouble getting it to version 2.7.6 so that I can install the react native CLI. Previously I changed it to 2.7.5 thinking that would work, but it didn't. I am not sure how I did this. The reason I need 2.7.6 is so that I can install the bundler for cocoa pods for IOS. Here is the gem env:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.1.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.7.5 (2021-11-24 patchlevel 203) [x86_64-darwin22]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/jonnywerthman/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/jonnywerthman/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-22
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5
     - /Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/bin
     - /Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5@global/bin
     - /Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/bin
     - /Users/jonnywerthman/.rbenv/shims
     - /Users/jonnywerthman/opt/miniconda3/bin
     - /Users/jonnywerthman/opt/miniconda3/condabin
     - /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Library/TeX/texbin
     - /Library/Apple/usr/bin
     - /Users/jonnywerthman/.rvm/bin
```

I need to make sure that it is switched to 2.7.6 and that the react native CLI actually reads it as 2.7.6 so that I can download the stuff I need.

Comment: Did you try the readme? https://github.com/rvm/rvm/blob/master/README.md#switching-between-ruby-versions

Comment: In my personal experience, I did not enjoy using `rvm`. Would recommend you to follow the installation of `asdf-vm` and then proceed with installing the Ruby plugin for `asdf`.

I have written this a few weeks ago at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74836951/16300383) , hopefully, it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `rbenv`.

https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv

It is less intrusive than rvm.