# Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.16 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bcrypt --version 3.1.16

Tags: ruby, installation, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

I'm receiving this giant error when i try to install bundler or rails or even when i try to start the server. any suggestions please? I am a beginner and have no idea what to do??? I already tried what the error suggested (install libyaml) and reinstalling ruby but it still does the same thing. Also tried gem pristine all but nothing.

```
gem install bundler

Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.16 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bcrypt --version 3.1.16
Ignoring bindex-0.8.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bindex --version 0.8.1
Ignoring bootsnap-1.13.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bootsnap --version 1.13.0
Ignoring bootsnap-1.7.5 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bootsnap --version 1.7.5
Ignoring byebug-11.1.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine byebug --version 11.1.3
Ignoring date-3.3.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine date --version 3.3.3
Ignoring debug-1.7.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine debug --version 1.7.1
Ignoring debug-1.6.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine debug --version 1.6.2
Ignoring digest-3.1.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine digest --version 3.1.0
Ignoring eventmachine-1.2.7 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine eventmachine --version 1.2.7
Ignoring ffi-1.15.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.3
Ignoring ffi-1.15.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.1
Ignoring ffi-1.15.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.0
/Users/angie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/yaml.rb:3: warning: It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
Traceback (most recent call last):
        23: from /Users/angie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
        22: from /Users/angie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:44:in `run'
        21: from /Users/angie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:79:in `do_configuration'
        20: from /Users/angie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:79:in `new'
        19: from /Users/angie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:182:in `initialize'
        18: from /Users/angie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:332:in `load_file'
        17: from /Users/angie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:715:in `load_yaml'
        16: from /Users/angie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
        15: from /Users/angie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
        14: from /Users/angie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/yaml.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        13: from /Users/angie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
        12: from /Users/angie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
        11: from /Users/angie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
        10: from /Users/angie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
         9: from /Users/angie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
         8: from /Users/angie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych/nodes.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
         7: from /Users/angie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
         6: from /Users/angie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
         5: from /Users/angie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych/nodes/node.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
         4: from /Users/angie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
         3: from /Users/angie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
         2: from /Users/angie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych/scalar_scanner.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
         1: from /Users/angie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
/Users/angie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require': dlopen(/Users/angie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/strscan-3.0.4/lib/strscan.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Users/angie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/strscan-3.0.4/lib/strscan.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/local/lib/strscan.bundle' (no such file), '/usr/lib/strscan.bundle' (no such file) - /Users/angie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/strscan-3.0.4/lib/strscan.bundle (LoadError)
```

Comment: These errors cannot be from `gem install bundler` because `bundler` has no dependencies. Also clearly psych exists because it it part of your stacktrace so I am really not certain what is going on here and the issue is going to be difficult to recreate as is.

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks for answering!! Do you have any suggestions as to what can be done?

Comment: What do you get when you run `ruby -v`? Looks like you're on a Mac, in which case, first make sure that you're using RVM's Ruby, and not the system package manager's Ruby. If it's the latter, make RVM's Ruby as default for global.

Comment: @AshvithShetty thanks for helping also! this is what I get 
ruby 2.7.4p191 (2021-07-07 revision a21a3b7d23) [arm64-darwin21]

Comment: @angiem103 if it is possible, could you switch from `rvm` to `asdf`? Personally, I've never liked `rvm`, as it has never worked properly for me. You can follow the instructions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74836951/16300383).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't switch since it's for a school project :/ @AshvithShetty